# jquery animation not working in android

Tags: android, jquery, ios, html

I have html doc with jquery animation looks very much alike: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/LittleBoxesMenu/

and it works fine on browser but not working on android `WebView` .
Why not?
Is there some catch with jquery and android?

EDIT: did some testing on iPhone and everything is working just fine, still no idea why not working in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem solved, quite simple at the end, in android app imported apache.cordova package, extended PhoneGap class and simply loaded URL. And that was it.

```
package voi.tii.yu;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class PhonegapActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/page2/index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: do we have to add their lib cordovas? and what is that droidGap cud you please help me out :( ?

Comment: just import cordova package as in example. as for DroidGap, thats phonegap class which is nicely written, so just inherit (extend) it. good luck and regards.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) clearly state that Android's WebView doesn't use JavaScript:

> By default, a WebView provides no browser-like widgets, does not
>   enable JavaScript and web page errors are ignored. If your goal is
>   only to display some HTML as a part of your UI, this is probably fine;
>   the user won't need to interact with the web page beyond reading it,
>   and the web page won't need to interact with the user. If you actually
>   want a full-blown web browser, then you probably want to invoke the
>   Browser application with a URL Intent rather than show it with a
>   WebView.

Comment: JavaScript is disabled by default, but there is interface that it can be used, see here http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html and it works lovely

Comment: I wasnt, untill now, tnx anyway for your trouble mate. (guess I should mention it was question about app, but I thought it was obvious when using webview)